# How to detect pinch gesture in ScrollView in React-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using scrollView like this

```
<ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
  <Text />
   <Some components />
  <Webview />
</ScrollView>
```

And Webview has height and can scroll too. also webview should zoom in/out.
but when i try zoom in/out not really zooming properly. 
after then, i realised scrollview interrupt pinching zoom.

So I added props in

```
<ScrollView scrollEnabled={this.state.isScrollEnabled} / >
```

then decide scroll if pinch event detect or not.
I searched about this issue, and was recommended to use PanResponder but i still dont know how to detect pinch Event... 
Help me please.
(+) should be working Android and IOS both..

Answer (score 0):

Use this library: https://github.com/kiddkai/react-native-gestures (it is using PanResponder). Wrap your ListView with Gesture View according to the docs, assign handler on pinch gesture, and in the handler decide if scrolling should be enabled or not for the list by changing the value of this.state.isScrollEnabled. That should work.